# CSV to JSON in python3 with repeted values

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, csv

I need to convert CSV with hundreds of rows to JSON in such a way that i need to get the key values repeating.

Here is what i have used to convert it to the present state

```
#Quest 1
import csv 
import json 
def make_json(csvFilePath, jsonFilePath): 
      
    # create a dictionary 
    data = {} 
      
    # Open a csv reader called DictReader 
    with open(csvFilePath, encoding='utf-8') as csvf: 
        csvReader = csv.DictReader(csvf) 
          
        # Convert each row into a dictionary  
        # and add it to data 
        for rows in csvReader: 
              
            # Assuming a column named 'No' to 
            # be the primary key 
            key = rows['MMSA'] 
            data[key] = rows 
  
    # Open a json writer, and use the json.dumps()  
    # function to dump data 
    with open(jsonFilePath, 'w', encoding='utf-8') as jsonf: 
        jsonf.write(json.dumps(data, indent=4)) 
          
csvFilePath = r'/home/user/Downloads/mmsa-icu-beds.csv'
jsonFilePath = r'/home/user/Downloads/mmsa-icu-beds.json'
  

make_json(csvFilePath, jsonFilePath)
```

The CSV file i have is:
[Current csv](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PzfTe.png)

What i am currently getting is this JSON format

```
{"MMSA": "Manhattan, KS", "total_percent_at_risk": "47.29%", "high_risk_per_ICU_bed": "4489.84875", "high_risk_per_hospital": "8979.6975", "icu_beds": "8", "hospitals": "4", "total_at_risk": "35918.79"}
{"MMSA": "Hilton Head Island-Bluffton-Beaufort, SC", "total_percent_at_risk": "62.72%", "high_risk_per_ICU_bed": "3904.163571", "high_risk_per_hospital": "36438.86", "icu_beds": "28", "hospitals": "3", "total_at_risk": "109316.58"}
{"MMSA": "Kahului-Wailuku-Lahaina, HI", "total_percent_at_risk": "59.13%", "high_risk_per_ICU_bed": "3860.557", "high_risk_per_hospital": "19302.785", "icu_beds": "20", "hospitals": "4", "total_at_risk": "77211.14"}
{"MMSA": "Spartanburg, SC", "total_percent_at_risk": "66.12%", "high_risk_per_ICU_bed": "3786.115556", "high_risk_per_hospital": "85187.6", "icu_beds": "45", "hospitals": "2", "total_at_risk": "170375.2"}
{"MMSA": "Baton Rouge, LA", "total_percent_at_risk": "66.60%", "high_risk_per_ICU_bed": "3459.7325", "high_risk_per_hospital": "39000.62091", "icu_beds": "124", "hospitals": "11", "total_at_risk": "429006.83"}
{"MMSA": "Rockingham County-Strafford County, NH, Metropolitan Division", "total_percent_at_risk": "57.72%", "high_risk_per_ICU_bed": "3365.052", "high_risk_per_hospital": "40380.624", "icu_beds": "60", "hospitals": "5", "total_at_risk": "201903.12"}
{"MMSA": "Salisbury, MD-DE", "total_percent_at_risk": "68.32%", "high_risk_per_ICU_bed": "3292.271176", "high_risk_per_hospital": "37312.40667", "icu_beds": "68", "hospitals": "6", "total_at_risk": "223874.44"}
```

Expecting JSON format:

```
{"MMSA": "Manhattan, KS", "Manhattan, KS total_percent_at_risk": "47.29%", "Manhattan, KS high_risk_per_ICU_bed": "4489.84875", "Manhattan, KS high_risk_per_hospital": "8979.6975", "Manhattan, KS icu_beds": "8", "Manhattan, KS hospitals": "4", "Manhattan, KS total_at_risk": "35918.79"}
```

Comment: Share your conversion code.

Comment: I have mentioned it now

Comment: so you're only expecting the first element? Or are you trying to put the `MMSA` value at the beginning of each key? I would thing the format you are trying to get will make the data MUCH more difficult to work with

Comment: Yes you are exactly correct but i want to feed it to a NLP model later and this is the only way i can make it more language like

Comment: Paste your CSV as text not an image or link.

Answer (score 0):

you managed to convert the csv into a dict with the column headers as keys. In a next step you can update this keys based on the value of "MMSA".

your question boils down to "How to update dict keys based on one of its values".

Here is one way of doing it:

```
first_step = {"MMSA": "Manhattan, KS", "total_percent_at_risk": "47.29%", "high_risk_per_ICU_bed": "4489.84875", "high_risk_per_hospital": "8979.6975", "icu_beds": "8", "hospitals": "4", "total_at_risk": "35918.79"}

mmsa = first_step["MMSA"]


def convert_key(key):
    if key == "MMSA":
        return key
    else:
        return mmsa + " " + key


second_step = {convert_key(key): value for key, value in first_step.items()}

>>>> {'MMSA': 'Manhattan, KS', 'Manhattan, KS total_percent_at_risk': '47.29%', 'Manhattan, KS high_risk_per_ICU_bed': '4489.84875', 'Manhattan, KS high_risk_per_hospital': '8979.6975', 'Manhattan, KS icu_beds': '8', 'Manhattan, KS hospitals': '4', 'Manhattan, KS total_at_risk': '35918.79'}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to grab the value of the MMSA key for each item in the list of dicts, then construct a dictionary with that same value at the beginning of each key `f'{row["MMSA"]} {k}': v` . This should work for you:

```py
import json

# data retuned by your csv
csv_data = [
    {"MMSA": "Manhattan, KS", "total_percent_at_risk": "47.29%", "high_risk_per_ICU_bed": "4489.84875",
        "high_risk_per_hospital": "8979.6975", "icu_beds": "8", "hospitals": "4", "total_at_risk": "35918.79"},
    {"MMSA": "Hilton Head Island-Bluffton-Beaufort, SC", "total_percent_at_risk": "62.72%", "high_risk_per_ICU_bed": "3904.163571",
        "high_risk_per_hospital": "36438.86", "icu_beds": "28", "hospitals": "3", "total_at_risk": "109316.58"},
    {"MMSA": "Kahului-Wailuku-Lahaina, HI", "total_percent_at_risk": "59.13%", "high_risk_per_ICU_bed": "3860.557",
        "high_risk_per_hospital": "19302.785", "icu_beds": "20", "hospitals": "4", "total_at_risk": "77211.14"},
    {"MMSA": "Spartanburg, SC", "total_percent_at_risk": "66.12%", "high_risk_per_ICU_bed": "3786.115556",
        "high_risk_per_hospital": "85187.6", "icu_beds": "45", "hospitals": "2", "total_at_risk": "170375.2"},
    {"MMSA": "Baton Rouge, LA", "total_percent_at_risk": "66.60%", "high_risk_per_ICU_bed": "3459.7325",
        "high_risk_per_hospital": "39000.62091", "icu_beds": "124", "hospitals": "11", "total_at_risk": "429006.83"},
    {"MMSA": "Rockingham County-Strafford County, NH, Metropolitan Division", "total_percent_at_risk": "57.72%",
        "high_risk_per_ICU_bed": "3365.052", "high_risk_per_hospital": "40380.624", "icu_beds": "60", "hospitals": "5", "total_at_risk": "201903.12"},
    {"MMSA": "Salisbury, MD-DE", "total_percent_at_risk": "68.32%", "high_risk_per_ICU_bed": "3292.271176",
        "high_risk_per_hospital": "37312.40667", "icu_beds": "68", "hospitals": "6", "total_at_risk": "223874.44"},
]

# super fancy comprehension with unpacking
json_data = [{'MMSA': row['MMSA'],  # keep the MMSA key
              **{f'{row["MMSA"]} {k}': v  # combine with the other keys and add the MMSA value
                 for k, v in row.items()
                 if k != 'MMSA'}}
             for row in csv_data]

def write_json(path, data, indent=4):
    with open(path, 'w') as file:
        json.dump(data, file, indent=indent)

write_json('./mmsa-icu-beds.json', json_data)
```

json output:

```json
[
    {
        "MMSA": "Manhattan, KS",
        "Manhattan, KS total_percent_at_risk": "47.29%",
        "Manhattan, KS high_risk_per_ICU_bed": "4489.84875",
        "Manhattan, KS high_risk_per_hospital": "8979.6975",
        "Manhattan, KS icu_beds": "8",
        "Manhattan, KS hospitals": "4",
        "Manhattan, KS total_at_risk": "35918.79"
    },
    {
        "MMSA": "Hilton Head Island-Bluffton-Beaufort, SC",
        "Hilton Head Island-Bluffton-Beaufort, SC total_percent_at_risk": "62.72%",
        "Hilton Head Island-Bluffton-Beaufort, SC high_risk_per_ICU_bed": "3904.163571",
        "Hilton Head Island-Bluffton-Beaufort, SC high_risk_per_hospital": "36438.86",
        "Hilton Head Island-Bluffton-Beaufort, SC icu_beds": "28",
        "Hilton Head Island-Bluffton-Beaufort, SC hospitals": "3",
        "Hilton Head Island-Bluffton-Beaufort, SC total_at_risk": "109316.58"
    },
    {
        "MMSA": "Kahului-Wailuku-Lahaina, HI",
        "Kahului-Wailuku-Lahaina, HI total_percent_at_risk": "59.13%",
        "Kahului-Wailuku-Lahaina, HI high_risk_per_ICU_bed": "3860.557",
        "Kahului-Wailuku-Lahaina, HI high_risk_per_hospital": "19302.785",
        "Kahului-Wailuku-Lahaina, HI icu_beds": "20",
        "Kahului-Wailuku-Lahaina, HI hospitals": "4",
        "Kahului-Wailuku-Lahaina, HI total_at_risk": "77211.14"
    },
    {
        "MMSA": "Spartanburg, SC",
        "Spartanburg, SC total_percent_at_risk": "66.12%",
        "Spartanburg, SC high_risk_per_ICU_bed": "3786.115556",
        "Spartanburg, SC high_risk_per_hospital": "85187.6",
        "Spartanburg, SC icu_beds": "45",
        "Spartanburg, SC hospitals": "2",
        "Spartanburg, SC total_at_risk": "170375.2"
    },
    {
        "MMSA": "Baton Rouge, LA",
        "Baton Rouge, LA total_percent_at_risk": "66.60%",
        "Baton Rouge, LA high_risk_per_ICU_bed": "3459.7325",
        "Baton Rouge, LA high_risk_per_hospital": "39000.62091",
        "Baton Rouge, LA icu_beds": "124",
        "Baton Rouge, LA hospitals": "11",
        "Baton Rouge, LA total_at_risk": "429006.83"
    },
    {
        "MMSA": "Rockingham County-Strafford County, NH, Metropolitan Division",
        "Rockingham County-Strafford County, NH, Metropolitan Division total_percent_at_risk": "57.72%",
        "Rockingham County-Strafford County, NH, Metropolitan Division high_risk_per_ICU_bed": "3365.052",
        "Rockingham County-Strafford County, NH, Metropolitan Division high_risk_per_hospital": "40380.624",
        "Rockingham County-Strafford County, NH, Metropolitan Division icu_beds": "60",
        "Rockingham County-Strafford County, NH, Metropolitan Division hospitals": "5",
        "Rockingham County-Strafford County, NH, Metropolitan Division total_at_risk": "201903.12"
    },
    {
        "MMSA": "Salisbury, MD-DE",
        "Salisbury, MD-DE total_percent_at_risk": "68.32%",
        "Salisbury, MD-DE high_risk_per_ICU_bed": "3292.271176",
        "Salisbury, MD-DE high_risk_per_hospital": "37312.40667",
        "Salisbury, MD-DE icu_beds": "68",
        "Salisbury, MD-DE hospitals": "6",
        "Salisbury, MD-DE total_at_risk": "223874.44"
    }
]
```